# Free Hand Drawing implementation on iPad

Tags: ipad, drawing

I am working on developing a free hand drawing application for the iPad. I have just started out developing the application. I have so far succeeded in capturing the touch points. But, I am unable to render these pixels on the screen. 
Are their any particular methods to perform the task? Please help!
Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Hey Amitabh,I got [This](http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=132024) while surfing,may be helpful to you. You can get the zip file of the code in the same link,they are implementing freehand tool in the application.
Thanks.

Comment: Make it a habit to check your post frequently to get a correct path otherwise your post will be hidden behind a bunch of other posts.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to maintain a list of points captured and render them to the UIView instance corresponding to your app's canvas. If you want a more detailed answer, we would need a more detailed question (eg, code you have so far, structure of your GUI, etc)

Answer (score 0):

store the last point and use a CGContext to draw a bezier curve (CGContextAddCurveToPoint()) from the last point to the current point. You will probably need to not do this every time the touchesMoved instead make an accumulator.

```
static int accum = 0;
if ((accum == 0) || (accum == threshold)) {
// drawing code goes here
accum = 0;
}
accum++;
```

threshold should be an instance variable. You can change the threshold dynamically if you need more precision on curves.

Comment: for smooth lines you will need to store up the points in an array and then use some AI to find a smooth line that passes through the points. You could also try particles using OpenGL. Heres a resource: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline